# GWT - Load a configuration item from context.xml

Tags: java, xml, tomcat, gwt

I have a GWT RPC application deployed to Tomcat 8, and I want the server code to load some configuration data  (hostname and port to another service). Otherwise the service works fine. I have read multiple suggestions but I cant get it to work.

A snippet from my Tomcat context.xml (I'm aware that context.xml requires me to restart tomcat when changed - that is OK).

```
<Context reloadable="true">

  <Parameter name="config_hostname" value="192.168.2.199" override="false"/>
  <Parameter name="config_port" value="8888" override="false"/>
```

In my service implementation I have a setup() method. In that I try to access the config by:

```
String hostname = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("config_hostname");
String port = getServletConfig().getInitParameter("config_port");
```

however that doesnt work. Can anyone put me on the right track?

----------------------- update -------------------

I have tried putting the info in web.xml like this

```
<web-app>
<context-param>
    <param-name>hostname</param-name>
    <param-value>192.168.2.199</param-value>
</context-param>
</web-app>
```

and using it like this (both works!) :

```
String h1=getServletConfig().getServletContext().getInitParameter("hostname");
String h2=getServletContext().getInitParameter("hostname");
```

however I don't want to put it in web.xml since I want to have a different setting  for each deployment. Tomcat have conf/server.xml och conf/context.xml and I have tried those but I get NULL in the above calls then.

Which is the best way of storing server-side configurations? Please be detailed in your answer.

I have read doumentation at http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html but I obviously don't understand it.

Comment: Do you have this code in the `ServletContextListener`, or in the `RemoteServiceServlet`? The `ServletContextListener#contextInitialized` method is called once when the server starts, which is where I would generally add such code.

Comment: I have it in a method in my class with this def: "public class MyService extends RemoteServiceServlet".

Comment: Have you tried putting the init parameters into web.xml, instead of context.xml? I have the following element in my web.xml file (this is a child of the "web-app" element): `<context-param><param-name>ConfigFilename</param-name><param-value>cfg/FosterAPet.cfg</param-value></context-param>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer here in the tomcat docs at /docs/config/context.html

The syntax in context.xml should be (I was correct from the beginnig here):

```
<Context>
  <Parameter name="hostname" value="<some-ip-address>" override="false"/>
</Context>
```

and the call to read it should be:

```
getServletConfig().getServletContext().getInitParameter("hostname");
  OR    
getServletContext().getInitParameter("hostname");
```

I'm sure I have a lot more to learn (for example to have separat params for separate web applications in Tomcat, but this is good for now).